# element.insertAdjacentHTML is not using style of stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css

Solved, the problem was that I was adding some divs with the insertAdjacentHTML and that doesn't work.

Sorry if the answer is obvious but I am using insertAdjacentHTML to add HTML to the page but when the page loads it doesn't have any style of my stylesheet.

I've seen that it's possible to add the CSS when I am adding the HTML to the page but it's a lot of CSS and I don't know if it's the best.

The code is something like this:

```
function addDiv() {
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.id = "IDHere";
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
    let s = document.getElementById("IDHere");
    s.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "htmlHere");

}
```

Comment: If I do [something like that](https://jsfiddle.net/7f6xaecw/), it works. So you're going to have to be a bit more specific. Can you show us a minimal example of it not working?

Comment: I've made some modifications and it worked when I inserted a <p>, but I was inserting some divs can it be the problem?